# Reinstalling Samsung Home on Samsung Galaxy Y Duos

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-touchwiz

I had removed Samsung Home and made another launcher as the default home screen. I now need to reinstall Samsung Home; and I have tried moving both the APK and the ODEX file for Samsung Home into the `/system/app` folder, and tried to set the proper permissions, but this didn't work.

Any other suggestions (other than restoring the Nandroid backup with CWM)?

Comment: A suggestion for next time: you don't need to remove the default launcher to start using another one. You can choose between the two with a *chooser* the same way you can for web browsers or any other kind of app.

Comment: @DanHulme: Frankly speaking, I went into an uninstalling spree after rooting my phone. And I do know of the chooser

Comment: That's good. I'd still like to make sure that anyone else who finds this question knows there's an easier way.